# Why do we need compiling and linking separately?

Tags: c++, c

Is that possible to link at the time of compiling, and remove the separate linking step?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, theoretically yes.

Comment: Linking means bundling together object files and object Files comes only after compilation.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "at the time of". You need to have individual functions compiled before you can link the call of one function to another - so it has to be sequential. But it could be "part of the same workflow" so you don't "see" there are two different steps...

Comment: ok if so,when compiler compiles the first line ,how do it will link before completing the main loop(entry function)?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore-->entry function.

Comment: Generally it cant compile one line at a time, it is an iterative process, first pass converts the user source code into an internal code, then it iterates on that code for various reasons then as the backend generates the assemble or machine code it iterates some more.  External references are resolved at link time, requiring a second step with all the modules required available.

Comment: Thank u so much guys ...helped ton..but still many confusions

Comment: Define "at the time of compiling".  It's certainly possible to compile and (partially) link from a single command line invocation; this is, in fact, the default for all Unix and Windows compilers.  On the other hand, in almost all cases, a significant part of the "linking" occurs at run-time, when separate libraries are loaded.

Comment: One reason to keep linking separate from compilation is that you might want to write different parts of your program in different languages.  That would mean using different compilers (that generate compatible object files) which are then handled by the linker.  (After all, you tagged this question with two different languages.)

Comment: @dwelch Or not.  Most modern systems support (and even insist on, for the system library) dynamic loading; you only link against the libraries at run-time.

Comment: exactly, separately compiled, separately linked...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You compile one or more translation units at a time, but as far as the language is concerned each TU is considered in isolation when compiling. You link one or more translation units together.

So, if all the TUs in the program are compiled at the same time, you can link them at that time (well, normally the linking would be immediately after the compilation, but that's an internal detail and there's nothing to stop you from writing a compiler/linker that somehow interleaves the steps so that there's no single point that occurs after all compilation has finished but before any linking starts).

However, if you only compile one TU out of many that will later be linked together to make a program, then of course you cannot link at the same time. Link with what? The other TUs might not even have been written yet, especially if the TU you are compiling is for distribution as a staticly-linked library.

Comment: When compiler compiles the first line ,how do it will link before completing the main loop(entry function)?

Comment: A lot of modern compilers only partially compile in the "compile" step; the actual generation of machine code is left until what is traditionally called the "link" step.  (And of course, with DLLs, a lot of what was traditionally considered linking is deferred until run-time.)

Comment: Concerning your first paragraph: the standard defines 9 phases of translation.  It very carefully avoids the terms "compiling" and "linking", but translation units are combined in phase 8 (which is done by the "compiler" in the most common systems today).  And of course, in most general purpose systems (Unix, Windows), a large part of phase 9 doesn't occur until the program is invoked.  The OPs question really begs the point: what does he mean by "compiling", "linking" and "at the time".  The only reasonable interpretation I can think of is by the invocation of a single command.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: yes, it's entirely possible. In fact, it's actually been done.

Some old Pascal compilers (e.g., early versions of Turbo Pascal) didn't have a separate linker. To create your executable, you compiled all the code together. Rather than track which standard library functions were used, and linking in only those that were needed, they simply copied the entire standard library (all ~8 kilobytes of it) into the executable.

To make this practical, you clearly need a fast compiler, small projects, or (probably) both.

When you were working on a system with 64 kilobytes of RAM and mass storage was a floppy disk drive that held around 100 to 200 kiloybtes or so, you weren't left with a lot of choice about that. Nowadays, I can't quite imagine anybody putting up with the same (or even similar) limitations.

All that said, it's not a model that fits very well with C or C++. They were designed from the beginning with the assumption of separate compilation and linking. Quite a few parts of the language proper (e.g., file-level static variables) only really work when you at least imitate separate linking.

Comment: Even today, standard Pascal has no provisions for separate compile.  (That's surely one of the reasons why nobody uses it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: One minor caveat. IIRC, at some point an ISO standard has to be either re-ratified, or else it's automatically withdrawn. If that's correct, I'm pretty sure there really *is* no such thing as standard Pascal any more; the standard's undoubtedly been withdrawn.

Comment: Do you consider your answer to be true when the question was explicitly tagged "C" and not "Pascal"? Especially in light of your last sentence. I find it curious that two answers from two "100k-plus-reputation" people start, respectively, with "Short answer: no", and "Short answer: yes".

Comment: @Floris: Yes, it's sort of true, even in C. Although it's distinctly less common, it's possible to do the same with C, and a few such implementations have existed (I just don't remember their names as well any more -- seems like BDS C may have been one of them, but I'm not sure).

Comment: @JerryCoffin The last _revision_ of the Pascal standard was around 1990.  And I think it is still active; there is a GNU Pascal compiler which claims to implement it.  There is a rule concerning re-ratification, but it doesn't (or didn't) take many people to handle that, and there are always a few faithful, regardless of the language.  (But this might be less the case with Pascal, given that even its inventor, Wirth, has moved on.)

Comment: @Floris I'm not sure it matters.  The point is, such a thing is possible.  (Arguably, g++ and VC++ do it in C++.  At least when I invoke `g++ mysource.cc` or `cl mysource.cc`, I get an executable.  They both use several different sub-processes to get there, but I'm not sure that's relevant---g++, at least, uses 3 or more sub-processes even when you invoke it with `-c`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, doing a quick check, the Pascal standard (ISO 7185) was reviewed and re-confirmed in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

To make you understand better a small explanation of compilation and linking process taking gcc as an example. This I hope will make you understand why linking while compiling is difficult.

The compiler translate source code from one language to another. The gcc compiler translate C code to assembler. The assembler takes assembly code and transforms it into object code. Although object code is mostly composed of machine code, it cannot be executed by the operating system. Object code does not have the necessary references to external functions and libraries to properly operate.

A linker takes the various outputs of a compiler and combines them to create an application.

Sources files are compiled separately by the compiler. Those sources might reference a function that exists elsewhere. The compiler leaves empty references to those functions.

The linker fills those references using the compiled output of all the files and the libraries available on the system. Once all the empty references have been resolved, the linker combines all the compiler output to create an executable.

Comment: But this is very specific to g++, and not the usual procedure.  In general, the compiler will translate the source code (after preprocessing) to some intermediate format, traditionally object code (which contains a direct binary representation of machine instructions), but often today to some sort of byte code (and practically never to assembler).  And the "linker" will almost never actually link everything; DLLs (including the interface to the system) are linked at run-time.

Comment: Also, this isn't really an accurate description of how g++ works.  g++ is a driver program, which invokes a number of other programs to do the actual work: there is no real "compiler" in the classical sense.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, yes, it's possible, but you're probably not going to see any implementation do that.

For example, suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  printf( "Hello, world\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling, I get the following machine code:

```
        .file   "hello.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello, world"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
        pushq   %rbp
.LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI1:
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

Note that the generated machine code calls the library function `puts`<sup>1</sup>, but the machine code for the `puts` function is not part of the object file.

That's why you need the secondary linking step; when you compile a translation unit, if it calls a function defined in another translation unit or library, that machine code isn't immediately available to the compiler.  The linking step is necessary to resolve all the references to external functions and to include the machine code for those functions in the final executable.

---

<sup>1.  This version of gcc will replace `printf` with `puts` if you're only passing a single argument.</sup>

Comment: Why is "linking" a "separate step"?  You need at least two "separate steps" to get the assembler output, and two separate steps after that to get an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling and linking separately allows for only compiling the translation units that have changed.

This is good because it allows faster building on large projects and reduced testing on critical projects.

In general the compiling phase is the slowest.  Text has to be searched and an intermediate form (object file) is built.

The linking phase is faster because it looks up symbols in tables and performs address and symbol resolution.

By not compiling every file each time in a large system, time is saved.

Also, testing time is saved because once a translation unit is compiled and tested, it can be left alone.  Only the translation units that were modified need to be retested.

One example is a data file coded as an initialized array.  This data, such as font bitmaps, is very unlikely to change.  The translation unit is compiled once and saved as an object file.  This cut down our build time from 5 minutes to 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, it is not possible.

Even if you placed all your code into a single tranlation unit, the libraries used by your program would need to be linked in.

Comment: What if they weren't using any library calls?

Comment: @JohnBode You'd still need the C/C++ runtime.

Comment: @JohnBode: James is right. While it is theoretically possible to work on an applicaiton that does not use any external code, chances are that you at the very least depend on the runtime and some OS support

Comment: What about freestanding implementations that don't have an OS or runtime?

Comment: @JohnBode: Those fall in the *uncommon* from my point of view... embedded developers will disagree, but I'd say that most people do use some runtime or another

Comment: The short answer is that, for any reasonable definition, g++ and VC++ do it.