# Makefile -o, why need .o

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors

#### when we want to compile a multi file together.

#### Why we need to convert .c file to .o in the makefile instead of just gcc file1.c file2.c -o newfile

For example

```
\\ in make file
file: file1.c file2.c 
     gcc file1.c file2.c -o combination

\\ we can just call make in the terminal
\\ i have watch video on youtube, why people using file1.o file2.o. why we need to convert .c file to .o instead of just gcc the file and ./ execute it?
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Why do we need compiling and linking separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225453/why-do-we-need-compiling-and-linking-separately)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107659/in-makefile-when-do-we-use-o-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to.  Go ahead and do it that way; it will work fine for very simple cases.

Makefiles are useful when (a) you have a number of compiler flags you have to remember or tell other people about, and/or (b) you start to get enough files that recompiling all of them whenever anything changes takes too long so you only want to recompile the files that changed.